# Workflow approval for a Purchase Requisition having multiple line items

Tags: elsa-workflows

I need to create a workflow using ELSA to handle a purchase requisition process. The requisition includes several line items, and each item needs to go through its own approval cycle. When the purchase requisition workflow is submitted, it should initiate separate approval processes for each line item. Once all the line items are approved, the workflow should update the status of the purchase requisition in the application. If a purchase requisition is denied, all the line item workflows should be terminated, and the status of the workflow in the application should be updated accordingly. How can i implement this using Elsa Workflow?